# In which case we can use view or controller rendering?

Tags: sitecore

I know this is a very basic question, but it matters a lot for developers. Basically, I just need to know that when developers should use **view rendering** and **controller rendering**.

Answer (score 0):

To put it briefly, view rendering is to simply display data. It can be controller by the front end via filtering or transforming it but it will not interact with any of the underlying business logic.

Whereas a controller rendering is more so used when the user is going to manipulate that data on the backend and will have to follow those business rules.

Is that sufficient?